# Tabla temporal en MYSQL y el su uso en PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy haciendo este código:

```
<?php 
$tempSQL = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tempUsers
SELECT CONCAT(NOMBRE,' 'AP_PATERNO,' ',AP_MATERNO) AS NOMBRE,
EMP_ID, AREA FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE ESTADO = 1";
mysqli_query($conn,$tempSQL);
if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)<=0)
  echo 'No fue posible concretar la información';
else
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tempUsers WHERE EMP_ID = $num";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  if(!$result)
    echo 'Ocurrió un error interno en la base de datos';
  else
  {
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)<=0)
      echo 'No se encontraron coincidencias en la búsqueda';
    else
    {...}
  }
}

mysqli_query($conn,"DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tempUsers");
 ?>
```

Mi pregunta es, este código se ejecuta con el evento de Jquery `onkeyup` me preocupa el performance del servidor y la creación y destrucción de tablas temporales constantemente, creen que, sería mejor hacer un stored procedure cada hora que haga esta operación o el crear y destruir tablas no pueda afectar a la base de datos.

Gracias por su experiencia.

**ACTUALIZO CON MÁS INFORMACIÓN**
Este es el problema, estoy haciendo un buscador por id de empleado, nombre o área, buscar por las 3 áreas, la idea de hacer una tabla temporal es por que hay empleados que tengo su nombre completo con apellidos dentro del campo nombre o separados por nombre ap_paterno y ap_materno. Lo cuál no he encontrado forma de cuando sea una búsqueda por nombre me busque Juan + Lopez debido a que los campos están separados. La única forma que se me ocurrió es hacer una tabla temporal dónde concatenar esos nombres y hacer el query a esa tabla, de esa forma si funciona. Intenté crear en la base de datos la tabla temporal y tratar de recoger los datos, pero al momento de la conexión desde PHP me marca que la tabla no existe.
Y eso es por que estoy haciendo este experimento.

Comment: No encuentro sentido a tu tabla temporal, ejecuta el select directo y te quitas de problemas... El performance depende mucho de los datos y los índices que pueda tener tu tabla.

Comment: Crear y borrar tablas temporales cada vez que alguien levante el dedo del teclado es desproporcionado. Deberías explicar que es lo que pretendes con este comportamiento tan extraño, pero de verdad, no se me ocurre ningún motivo para hacerlo... estamos todos expectantes ;)

Comment: Listo, ya actualice el problema

Comment: ¿Por qué no usar vistas en lugar de tablas temporales? Creo que el rendimiento que obtendrías sería mejor ya que no es una SELECT especialmente compleja y te ahorrarías estar creando y (sobre todo) rellenando tablas continuamente.

Comment: @alberto-siurob yo tambien pienso que es una locura...Hay que pensar en otra solución.

Comment: _cuando sea una búsqueda por nombre me busque Juan+Lopez_ Muyyy mal la idea de crear tabla temporal para eso. Puedes construir una consulta dinámica en PHP y pasarla luego a la base de datos. No es tan complicado. Por ejemplo: si se llenaron los inputs `nombre` y `apellido` del formulario, crear una consulta con `WHERE nombre LIKE '%:nombre%'  AND apellido LIKE '%:apellido%'` si se llenó sólo el nombre:  `WHERE nombre LIKE '%:nombre%'` y si se llenó sólo el apellido: ` `WHERE LIKE '%:apellido%'`  y si no se llenó nada: `echo "Por favor introduzca datos a buscar;` ¿Ves? Ya lo tienes hecho.

Comment: Esque no es un formulario, es un solo input, donde busco por nombre completo, area o ID. Si aplico lo que tu propones quedaría así: ´SELECT *
 FROM TABLE WHERE NOMBRE LIKE ="%$data%"´ El problema es que, si el usuario teclea JUAN, me traerá toda la información, pero si teclea JUAN LOPEZ ahí se rompió el query, por que el nombre es JUAN no JUAN LOPEZ. Ahora agregale la búsqueda por ID y área, es una locura. Igual agradezco tu comentario @A.Cedano

Answer (score 2):

Mi sugerencia sería que no usaras tablas temporales para esto, especialmente si lo vas a ejecutar cada vez que el usuario pulsa una tecla en un formulario. El rendimiento de tu servidor de base de datos se verá afectado negativamente con toda la creación rellenado y destrucción de tablas temporales... todo por una `SELECT` que es relativamente sencilla.

En su lugar te recomendaría que usaras una vista. Esa vista, a la que puedes llamar "vistaPersonas", contendrá las columnas que necesitas: la concatenación de nombre, apellido paterno y apellido materno, el id y el área. Y entonces cuando se pulse una tecla, se consultaría la vista en lugar de usar un método complejo.

El código de creación de la vista sería sencillo (he corregido un error tipográfico, faltaba una coma):

```
CREATE VIEW vistaPersonas
    AS SELECT CONCAT(nombre, ' ', ap_paterno, ' ', ap_materno) AS nombre, emp_id, area 
       FROM   personas 
       WHERE  estado = 1
```

Y entonces, la petición se reduce considerablemente cuando se pulsa en el teclado (lo he cambiado para evitar las sentencias dinámicas, es más seguro usar sentencias preparadas):

> Nota: no he probado este código y puede contener errores

```
<?php 

  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM vistaPersonas WHERE emp_id = ?"); 
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $num);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

  if(!$result) {
    echo 'Ocurrió un error interno en la base de datos';
  } else {
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)<=0) {
      echo 'No se encontraron coincidencias en la búsqueda';
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: La verdad es que la `SELECT` es tan simple, que casi te podrías plantear hacer una `SELECT` con un campo calculado y ni siquiera tener que hacer nada de vistas ni tablas temporales.

Comment: Creo que la vista será mucho más fácil. Gracias Alvaro.

Answer (score 0):

Crear tablas temporales o vistas es casi lo mismo, consumen recursos del servidor, pues las vistas ya son en si un `select`, y todavía a ese le anidas otro `select` es cargarle trabajo.

Estoy de acuerdo que en este caso se haga el filtro sobre la tabla directa, y el `where` aplicar la concatenación de campos como ya especificaban:

```
where concat(ap_paterno, ' ', ap_materno, ' ', nombres) like '%lopez ruiz%' 
....
```

Incluso en ese mismo `where` puedes hacer un `CAST` o `CONVERT` al campo id para que te lo trate como `varchar` y lo incluyas en la misma búsqueda y simplifiques el código, de esta manera si el usuario pone letras o pone números el `query` te arrojaría un resultado muy certero